# Julia gui display an image gtk.jl

Tags: julia

How can I display an image using Gtk with Julia?

In my GUI, I have a button set up so when I click the button, my program will show the image in the GUI?  I haven't found any documentation about it on the official [Gtk.jl Docs](https://juliagraphics.github.io/Gtk.jl/latest/).

Answer (score 2):

This uses ImageView to do the image display, which gives you control of aspect ratio, zoom, pan, contrast-settings, and movie-player widgets "for free":

```
using Gtk, ImageView, TestImages

b = GtkButton("Click Me")
frame, c = ImageView.frame_canvas(:auto)
bx = GtkBox(:v)
push!(bx, frame)
push!(bx, b)
win = GtkWindow("My First Gtk.jl Program", 400, 200)
push!(win, bx)
Gtk.showall(win)

img = testimage("lighthouse")
imshow(c, img)
```

with result

[image: gui]

The dictionary that `imshow` returns allows you to interact programmatically with what's on the screen.

If you want to learn more, see the documentation at [ImageView](https://github.com/JuliaImages/ImageView.jl) and [GtkReactive](https://github.com/JuliaGizmos/GtkReactive.jl).

That said, the suggestion to try Makie may be a very good one.

Comment: How I can show image from local desktop using Gtk ? Help me please

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick!

```
using Gtk

win = GtkWindow("My First Gtk.jl Program", 400, 200)

a = GtkImage("path_to_image_file")

push!(win,a)

showall(win)
```

Note that I am not sure if it can render in the same window as the button you mentioned since I get the following error when I have a button and then push the image:

```
(<unknown>:69811): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:34:18.724: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkWindow, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkWindow can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkButton
```

Comment: You may want to check out Makie.jl since you can have buttons and images and such. That's exactly how I use makie!

Comment: You need to use a `GtkBox` to do layout for more than one widget.